# How do I add to a section in a line in JSON (python)?

Tags: python, json, file

I was wondering how I would add to a certain parameter of a JSON line with python. For example, here is my python:

```py
import json

file = open('jsonusers.json', 'r+')
read = file.read()
y = json.loads(read)
users = y["people"]
lines = [person for person in users if person["id"] == 457775659998248960]
for i in lines:
    print(i)
```

and here is my JSON file:

```
{"people": [{"id": 580040383883378710, "coins": 0}, {"id": 457775659998248960, "coins": 0}, {"id": 630506515484377099, "coins": 0}]}
```

If I wanted to add 1 to the coins of 457775659998248960, how would I do that then update it to the JSON file?

Comment: FYI, you can combine `file.read()` and `json.loads()` into `json.load(file)`

Comment: thanks, that will make it easier.

Comment: Just a suggestion: if you have to look up objects by their IDs it can be a good idea to store them in a dictionary with the id as key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can open the file in a context manager, load it into a variable, then iterate through the list, increment the value of a given key, and then write it back in:

```py
with open("jsonusers.json", "r") as fp:
    data = json.load(fp)

for person in data["people"]:
    if person["id"] == 457775659998248960:
        person["coins"] += 1

with open("jsonusers.json", "w+") as fp:
    json.dump(data, fp, sort_keys=True, indent=4) # kwargs are for beautification
```

---

**References:**

- [File context managers](https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/context_managers.html)

Comment: Thanks! I saw your comment about the kwargs, but what exactly does sort_keys and indent do?

Comment: oh hi diggy i didnt realize it was you :)

Comment: `sort_keys` sorts the keys alphanumerically (0-9, a-z), and `indent` makes the file's indentation level 4 spaces. If you open up the `.json` it'll be clearer to see. Haha, hey max!

Comment: Ok ill run it and take a look at the JSON file.